# Is it possible to shelve a deleted file in perforce?

Tags: perforce, p4v

I have a changelist where I've deleted a few files after consolidating their functionality. P4v errors when trying to shelve the removed files with the message "The system cannot find the file specified". (Hey perforce, that's kinda the point).

Is there any way to shelve this as a "pending deletion"? Keeping these files around would cause errors in my code. Even making them blank is a bit sketchy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open it for `delete` instead of `edit`.  This is `p4 delete` at the command line, or "Mark for Delete" in P4V.  (If it's currently open for edit, you might need to revert it first and then open it for delete instead.)

Comment: That was what I was looking for! Thanks!